# Familiarising with Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception

I can't figure out why my getHours() is catching InputMismatchException when I have only thrown InvalidHrExcep to the method itself. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            getHours();
            getAmPm();
            accept = true;
        }
        catch(InvalidHrExcep h)
        {
            System.out.println (h);
            accept = false;
            console.nextLine();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println (e);
            System.out.println("Input must be AM or PM.");
            accept = false;
            console.nextLine();
        }
    }while(accept == false);
}
```

My method for getHours()

```
public static int getHours() throws InvalidHrExcep
{
    System.out.print ("Enter hours: ");
    int hour = console.nextInt();

    if(hour > 0 && hour <= 12)
    {
        return hour;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidHrExcep();
    }
}
```

Comment: your getHours isn't catching anything. it might throw it, which is a different matter. I would recommend adding e.printStackTrace(); into your catch block, going through the stacktrace 'll make it easier to see where the exception is thrown. so far, there is no reason to believe it was thrown by getHours()

Comment: We have no idea what `getHours()` does.

Comment: Oops, ok I have added my getHours() method.

Comment: can you show the implementation of InvalidHrExcep if it is a Exception you have implemented?

Comment: what did you provide as input for the getHours() method? nextInt might throw that exception, if the input you've entered is not a valid int

Comment: @Sand it's quite unlikely for the constructor of one Exception type to throw a completely different one

Comment: Ok oops guys i realised that I only specify my condition to be a range of numbers. MY BAD! I kept testing using characters.

Answer (score 0):

`console.nextInt()` can definitely throw `InputMismatchException` exception, and your `getHours` method doesn't have to specify that exception in a `throws` clause, since it's an unchecked exception.

If you don't want `getHours()` to throw that exception, you should put `console.nextInt()` in a try block and catch it.